# react-redux-firebase doesn't store providerData properly on Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I was using Realtime Database and am now migrating to use Firestore. Previously, I was storing my `providerData` as an array, since one account can have multiple providers assigned. Right now, I'm trying to keep the same structure for Firestore, but it doesn't store the `providerData` object inside the array.

I saw some comments on how Firestore doesn't allow custom objects and already transformed the Firebase object into Javascript pure object.

My profileFactory is currently like this:

```
profileFactory: (data, profile) => {
  const helperProviderData = (profile.providerData || data.providerData || data.user.providerData);
  const providerData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(helperProviderData));
  return ({
    ...profile,
    role: 'user',
    providerData,
    test: providerData[0],
  });
}
```

On Firestore, I have the `test` field correctly populated, but the `providerData` field is set as an Array with one empty Object.

These are the versions:

```
"@firebase/app": "0.4.19",
"@firebase/auth": "0.12.1",
"@firebase/database": "0.5.7",
"@firebase/firestore": "1.6.1",
"react-redux-firebase": "^3.0.2",
"redux-firestore": "^0.11.0",
```

Is it possible to set as an Array of providers or I'll need to create a provider field for each provider accepted by my app?

Comment: In my opinion it should work properly. Can you provide example of `helperProviderData`?

Comment: Found out that the issue is not with the Firestore connection. For some reason which I'm not sure yet, when creating an object with `providerData`, the Objects inside the Array are empty, while if I pick the first position of the Array, I get the object properly. I'll still dig a bit more when I have more time.

Comment: That's why I am asking about it. I have tested all possible structures of data available in Firestore and didn't' found such behavior. Maybe the problem is with obtaining data from Firestore to `profile` argument